File access without directory listing
I have an OpenMediaVault server with a Samba share.
The share contains an installer for each client. I would like each client to be able to download and install their file as a guest however I do not wish each client to be able to browse the share and effectively see the listing of our clients.
Is it possible using Samba to give permissions to download a file if you know the exact path and filename however not allow a directory listing?

Yes, if you remove the Read/List permissions from directories.
Both Linux and Windows/SMB/NTFS use a similar file permission model where two separate flags control directory access – Read/List (Linux +r) allows directory listing while Execute/Traverse (Linux +x) allows direct access to items inside.
(Though all modern Windows versions grant directory Traverse implicitly even if it's not allowed via permissions, but this might not apply to Linux/Samba servers, and either way it doesn't affect your goal of disabling Read/List.)
But I would suggest that it would be more tidy to instead split up each client's files into their own subdirectory, and let each client's Samba account only access files in that directory.
